# How can I test my spring boot Service method that has an Authentication object as parameter?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, junit, mockito, keycloak

I am constructing a Spring Boot endpoint in Kotlin and I need to create tests for this. I could create a test for my controller class bellow:

```
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/servicos/solicitacoes")
class SolicitacaoController {


    @Autowired
    private lateinit var solicitacaoService: SolicitacaoService

    @PostMapping(consumes = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE])
    fun post(@RequestBody solicitacaoDTO: SolicitacaoDataClassDTO, @ApiIgnore authentication: Authentication): Solicitacao {
        return solicitacaoService.addSolicitacao(solicitacaoDTO, authentication)
    }
}
```

However, as my service class has an Authentication parameter I don't know how I can create a test for my service class.

This is my service class:

```
@Service
class SolicitacaoService {
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var solicitacaoRepository: SolicitacaoRepository

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var acessoSistema: AcessoSistema

    fun addSolicitacao(solicitacaoDTO: SolicitacaoDataClassDTO, authentication: Authentication): Solicitacao{
        val idInstitucional = acessoSistema.getIdInstitucional(authentication)
        // Some Businnes logic
        return solicitacaoRepository.save(solicitacao)
    }
}
```

The authentication process is made by a keycloak token, which the front-end needs to get to access back-end services.

I can test my Controller, because in my post request I send the token in the header of the request. However, for testing the method addSolicitacao in my Service, I need to create an Authentication object.

Any idea on how can I create a Test for my SolicitacaoService?
I am using JUnit and Mockito. I thought about to mock my SolicitacaoRepository in my SolicitacaoServiceTest. However, I don't know how can I create an object Authentication with the parameters of my Keycloak server.

This is my SolicitacaoServiceTest:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
//@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class SolicitacaoServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var solicitacaoService: SolicitacaoService

    @MockBean
    private lateinit var solicitacaoRepository: SolicitacaoRepository

    @Test
    fun quandoAdicionarSolicitacaoComUsuarioComum_entaoSolicitacaoDeveSerRetornada(){


    }


}
```